# Pyomo + Gurobi Scheduling Tasks within Working Hours

Tags: optimization, gurobi, scheduling, pyomo

I initially posted this on stackoverflow and got redirected here. You can view the old post  with formatted tables here: [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77439941/pyomo-gurobi-scheduling-tasks-within-working-hours?noredirect=1#comment136523339_77439941)

I have a python schedule optimization script using pyomo and the limited license version of gurobi. The script reads a csv list of Tasks and Artists. Each task has a task name, a duration in hours, dependencies, a link (an overarching group of tasks, in which the dependencies work within), pre-assigned artists (if any), and a buffer in hours before a dependent task can start after its completion. Each artist has an artist name and a list of task names they are capable of doing. The script returns assignments with start and end dates with a minimal makespan. Up to this point, the script works as intended.

As an example of the input data, here is the example case list of tasks:

[image: Example Task List]

And the example artist list:

[image: Example Artist List]

Although, in order to make it fully useful, I need the tasks to be only assigned from 09:00 to 17:00 every day. Tasks can and will span over multiple days. If the assignment overlaps multiple calendar days, the task should 'pause' from 17:00 to the next day at 09:00. This is where I'm struggling- I've made several attempts, but I can only go as far as restricting the schedule from 09:00-17:00 if the task duration stays below 8 hours (able to be assigned in a single day). My goal is to work off of this and eventually also add the functionality of assigning 'unavailable hours' for individual artists to accommodate booked vacation time, days/half-days off.

I'd dearly appreciate any guidance on how to tackle this obstacle- even if it means restructuring from square one!

Below is my entire script in it's current working state, without any consideration for working hours:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.util.infeasible import log_infeasible_constraints
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Load data from Excel
tasks_df = pd.read_excel('ProjectData.xlsx', sheet_name='Tasks')
artists_df = pd.read_excel('ProjectData.xlsx', sheet_name='Artists')

# Preprocess data
tasks = {}
assigned_tasks = {}
for _, row in tasks_df.iterrows():
    unique_task_name = f"{row['Task Name']}-{row['Link']}"
    tasks[unique_task_name] = {'duration': row['Duration'],
                               'dependencies': [] if pd.isna(row['Dependencies']) else [f"{dep.strip()}-{row['Link']}" for dep in row['Dependencies'].split(',')],
                               'buffer': row['Buffer']}

    if pd.notna(row['Assigned To']):
        assigned_tasks[unique_task_name] = row['Assigned To']

print(tasks)

# Ensuring task dependencies stay within their respective shot.
# Quick sanity check to ensure dependencies are correctly assigned.
for task, data in tasks.items():
    shot_id = task.split('-')[-1]
    for dep in data['dependencies']:
        dep_shot_id = dep.split('-')[-1]
        if shot_id != dep_shot_id:
            raise ValueError(f"Task {task} has a dependency {dep} from a different shot!")


for _, row in tasks_df.iterrows():
    unique_task_name = f"{row['Task Name']}-{row['Link']}"
    tasks[unique_task_name] = {'duration': row['Duration'],
                               'dependencies': [] if pd.isna(row['Dependencies']) else [f"{dep.strip()}-{row['Link']}" for dep in row['Dependencies'].split(',')],
                               'buffer': row['Buffer']}
    
    # Check for Dependency Existence:
    for dep in tasks[unique_task_name]['dependencies']:
        if dep not in tasks:
            raise KeyError(f"Dependency '{dep}' for task '{unique_task_name}' not found in tasks.")



artists = {row['Name']: {'tasks': row['tasks'].split(',')} for _, row in artists_df.iterrows()}

# Create a model
model = ConcreteModel()
model.TASKS = Set(initialize=tasks.keys())
model.ARTISTS = Set(initialize=artists.keys())

# Variables
model.start_time = Var(model.TASKS, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.z = Var(model.TASKS, model.ARTISTS, within=Binary)
model.makespan = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)

# Objective: Minimize makespan
model.obj = Objective(expr=model.makespan, sense=1)


# Additional Variable to manage overlapping tasks for artists
model.end_time = Var(model.TASKS, within=NonNegativeReals)


# Constraints

'''
This constraint enforces that a task is preassigned to an artist if it has been explicitly assigned in the input data.
It sets the binary variable model.z[task, artist] to 1 if the task is preassigned to the artist; otherwise, 
it allows model.z[task, artist] to be greater than or equal to 0.
'''
def preassigned_task_rule(model, task, artist):
    return model.z[task, artist] == 1 if task in assigned_tasks and assigned_tasks[task] == artist else model.z[task, artist] >= 0

model.preassigned_task_constr = Constraint(model.TASKS, model.ARTISTS, rule=preassigned_task_rule)



# Constraint to enforce task dependencies
def dependency_rule(model):
    for task in model.TASKS:
        if not tasks[task]['dependencies']: 
            continue  # Skip if the task has no dependencies
        
        for dep in tasks[task]['dependencies']:
            latest_dep_end_time = model.end_time[dep] + tasks[dep]['buffer']
            yield model.start_time[task] >= latest_dep_end_time

model.dependency_constr = ConstraintList(rule=lambda model=model: dependency_rule(model))





'''
This constraint calculates the end time of each task based on its start time and duration.
It enforces that the end time is equal to the start time plus the task's duration.
'''
def end_time_rule(model, task):
    return model.end_time[task] == model.start_time[task] + tasks[task]['duration']

model.end_time_constr = Constraint(model.TASKS, rule=end_time_rule)

'''
This constraint ensures that the makespan (the maximum end time) of the project is greater than or equal to the end time of each task.
It helps in minimizing the overall project duration.
'''
def makespan_rule(model, task):
    return model.makespan >= model.end_time[task]

model.makespan_constr = Constraint(model.TASKS, rule=makespan_rule)


M = max(task_data['duration'] for task_data in tasks.values()) * len(tasks)


# Defining a set of (task, prerequisite) pairs
model.PREREQUISITES = Set(within=model.TASKS*model.TASKS, initialize=[(task, prerequisite) for task in model.TASKS for prerequisite in tasks[task]['dependencies']])

'''
This constraint specifies that for each task with dependencies, the task's start time should 
be greater than or equal to the average end time of its dependencies.
This rule promotes task parallelization when dependencies are satisfied.
'''
def immediate_start_rule(model, task):
    prerequisites = tasks[task]['dependencies']
    if prerequisites:
        return model.start_time[task] >= sum(model.end_time[prerequisite] for prerequisite in prerequisites) / len(prerequisites)
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip  # Skip if there are no prerequisites

model.immediate_start_constr = Constraint(model.TASKS, rule=immediate_start_rule)


'''
This constraint encourages parallel execution of tasks of the same type (e.g., tasks with the same name) by different artists.
It ensures that if multiple artists are capable of performing the same task type, 
at most one artist is assigned to execute that task at the same time.
'''

def parallel_execution_rule(model, artist, task_i, task_j):
    if task_i >= task_j:  # skip duplicate pairs
        return Constraint.Skip
    
    task_name_i = task_i.split('-')[0]
    task_name_j = task_j.split('-')[0]
    
    # Check if the tasks are of the same type and if the artist can perform the task
    if task_name_i == task_name_j and artist in artists and task_name_i in artists[artist]['tasks']:
        other_artists = [a for a in artists if a != artist and task_name_i in artists[a]['tasks']]
        if other_artists:  # If there are other artists available
            return sum(model.z[task_i, artist] + model.z[task_j, artist] for artist in other_artists) <= 1
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip  # If no other artists are available, skip the constraint
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip  # Skip if tasks are not of the same type or artist can't perform them

model.parallel_execution_constr = Constraint(model.ARTISTS, model.TASKS, model.TASKS, rule=parallel_execution_rule)

'''
This constraint enforces that each task is assigned to exactly one artist.
It ensures that a task is not left unassigned and that it is assigned to a valid artist capable of performing that task.
'''
def assignment_rule(model, task):
    task_name = task.split('-')[0]
    possible_artists = [artist for artist, details in artists.items() if task_name in details['tasks']]
    return sum(model.z[task, artist] for artist in possible_artists) == 1

model.assignment_constr = Constraint(model.TASKS, rule=assignment_rule)

model.artist_assigned = Var(model.ARTISTS, model.TASKS, within=Binary)


'''
This constraint links the model.artist_assigned variable with the model.z variable to ensure consistency in assignment.
'''
def link_artist_assigned_rule(model, artist, task):
    return model.artist_assigned[artist, task] == model.z[task, artist]

model.link_artist_assigned = Constraint(model.ARTISTS, model.TASKS, rule=link_artist_assigned_rule)


# Big M constant
M = 10000  # A large number

# Create a binary variable to indicate whether tasks with the same name should overlap
model.overlap_allowed = Var(model.TASKS, model.TASKS, within=Binary)


# Constraint to prevent overlapping assignments for the same artist without a delay
def overlapping_tasks_rule(model, a, t1, t2):
    if t1 < t2:
        # Check if tasks t1 and t2 have the same name and artist can perform them
        task_name_t1, link_t1 = t1.split('-')[0], t1.split('-')[1]
        task_name_t2, link_t2 = t2.split('-')[0], t2.split('-')[1]

        if task_name_t1 == task_name_t2 and a in artists and task_name_t1 in artists[a]['tasks']:
            start_time_t1 = model.start_time[t1]
            end_time_t1 = start_time_t1 + tasks[t1]['duration']
            start_time_t2 = model.start_time[t2]
            end_time_t2 = start_time_t2 + tasks[t2]['duration']

            # Ensure that task t2 starts as soon as or just after task t1 ends (no delay)
            return (start_time_t2 >= end_time_t1 - 0.01) if task_name_t1 == 'Compositing' else Constraint.Skip

    return Constraint.Skip  # Skip if conditions are not met

model.overlapping_tasks_constr = Constraint(model.ARTISTS, model.TASKS, model.TASKS, rule=overlapping_tasks_rule)


# Solve
solver = SolverFactory('gurobi')
results = solver.solve(model, tee=True)

for task in model.TASKS:
    print(f"Task {task} has start time {model.start_time[task].value} and end time {model.end_time[task].value}")


if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.warning and
        results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
    print("Model is infeasible.")
    log_infeasible_constraints(model)
    
    # Debugging step: manually check some constraints or variable values
    for task in model.TASKS:
        print(f"Task {task} has start time {model.start_time[task].value} and end time {model.end_time[task].value}")
        
else:
    # Process results...
    pass


# Extract and write results to Excel
output_data = []
for task in model.TASKS:
    start = model.start_time[task].value
    end = start + tasks[task]['duration']
    
    # Define assigned_artist with a default value
    assigned_artist = None  
    
    for artist in model.ARTISTS:
        if model.z[task, artist].value == 1:
            assigned_artist = artist
            break
    
    # Ensure that a valid assigned_artist is found
    if assigned_artist is None:
        raise ValueError(f"No artist was assigned to task {task}. Check your optimization model.")
    
    output_data.append([task.split('-')[0], task.split('-')[1], tasks[task]['duration'], assigned_artist,
                        (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=start)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
                        (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=end)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')])


output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns=['Task Name', 'Link', 'Duration', 'Assigned Artist', 'Start Time', 'End Time'])
output_df.to_excel('OptimizedSchedule.xlsx', index=False)

print("Optimization completed and results written to 'OptimizedSchedule.xlsx'")
```

Comment: It isn't clear why you would need to do this.  Why not just convert the "elapsed time" afterwards into clock time and be done?  For instance, if the makespan of Shot 1 turns out to be 18.5 hours, then I can tell you it will finish at 11:30 on the 3rd day, right?  with a little widget you could convert any elapsed time into time-of-day.  Would that not be sufficient?

Comment: @Phil Franjo, welcome to OR.SE. It seems your issue more than being an optimization problem gets back to the programming side. Your problem is well known and its name is resource-constrained project schedule. Do you have any forces to use the programming module? There are very nice tools to illustrate and schedule what you want. e.g. [Ganttproject](https://www.ganttproject.biz/).

Comment: @AirSquid It would be, but my ultimate goal is to factor in booked time off and holidays, which would need to be able to be accessed while solving the problem to achieve the minimal makespan. For example, if a user is booked off for a week near the end of a project, it would be optimal to assign their task to the next available artist as it would expand the makespan.

Comment: @A.Omidi This tool is not what I'm looking for. I have tools to manually assign tasks and view them in a gantt format already- my goal with this is to add several complex factors and automatically produce long-term project schedules instantly.